# Adding part of a php page between an open and close shortcode tags

Tags: php, shortcode

I need to define as restricted only part of the site - to logged in users - and I will use the shortcode [private] ... [/private] with a php code inside.

I want to restrict only the line of 'attachments' so that it looks something like the code below:

```
<?php get_template_part('template-parts/single-property/video'); ?>
[private]
<?php get_template_part('template-parts/single-property/attachments'); ?>
[/private]
```

I researched and could not apply to my case any of the answers found in similar queries, in this and other forums. I'm sorry if this sounds repetitive to you.

Hopeless level! :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Remove the space in `<? php` and it should work fine. Edit given that the function does the echo and not just a return. If it's a return then you need to output it somehow with a loop or a simple echo depending on what the return is.

Comment: Hi, @andreas, thanks for your attention. So it does not work (even without the space between '<? Php').
I imagine the way it might be with the use of 'echo do_shortcode'. But I tried it in several ways and it did not work.

Comment: What does `get_template_part` do? Does it just get the template? Or does it echo the template? When the former, try adding `echo ` before `get_template_part`.

Comment: I think it calls the part with the content I want. I apologize, but I do not know how to do this (echo). It's a Wordpress page. You can see it at: https://casasprontasinvestidores.pt/novo/property/t3-setubal/
Attachments (which this line calls) refers to the section called 'Documentos' on this page. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any error message? Do the templates exist under `template-parts/single-property/`?

Comment: No error message is displayed. But the page does not load completely, when I insert the shortcode.

Comment: To contextualize I will post below a larger section of code:



    `<?php
    echo $property->virtual;
    echo '<br><br>';
    ?>
    </div>
    <hr class="prop-hr">
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/single-property/video'); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/single-property/attachments'); ?>
    <?php
    $amenities =  $property->get_amenities();
    if( !empty($amenities) ) :
    ?>`

Comment: google `How to enable WordPress error reporting` to switch on wordpress  debugging

Comment: I've enabled debugging mode, but the error file does not show anything related to this event.
The closest I could get was in this code, following a similar topic:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[private role="administrator"]'.get_template_part('template-parts/single-property/attachments').'[/private]'); ?>`

With this code the front end did not show any kind of error, but it just did not work (I tested the plugin on a page using the visual editor and it works normally).